# WCSession sendMessage in Xcode 7.0 (7A218) Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I use sendMessage from iWatch (Simulator) to iOS to awake iOS app:

```
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"userInfo", @"key", nil];


    if ([[WCSession defaultSession] isReachable]){ //iPhone is reachable
        NSLog(@"iPhone is reachable");

        [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:userInfo replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {
            NSLog(@"ReplyHandler run");
        } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            NSLog(@"iWatch sendMessage Error: %@", error);
       }
```

But I found that sendMessage only works if iOS app counterpart is either in Background or Foreground. If iOS app is not running at all, sendMessage cannot awake the iOS App. Both replyHandler and errorHandler were not called if App is not running in background / foreground.

This does not agree with the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:): Calling this method from your WatchKit extension while it is active and running wakes up the corresponding iOS app in the background and makes it reachable. Calling this method from your iOS app does not wake up the corresponding WatchKit extension.

I tested on Xcode Beta 5 and the same piece of code worked even if iOS app is not running.

Anyone encounter similar issues in latest Simulator and Xcode? 
Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a bug perhaps. Maybe file a bug report with Apple? If you do so, great if you report back with the radar number so that any perusing Apple engineers can easily find it!

Comment: @ccjensen, did you see the same thing? I was running on Simulator and not a real iWatch, do u have a real iWatch to check?

Comment: @John Did you file a radar? I'm getting the same thing w/ the Xcode 7 release version.

Comment: It's the correct way how iPhone is working. The documentation is misunderstood. The "wakes up the corresponding iOS app in the background" means the iOS app is in the background, it means it started yet, but pushed back to background by another app or by user and you could check it with doubble push the home button.